# IntelliSense in Visual Studio Code not working with python packages

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am fairly new to python. So I installed python and my editor is Visual Studio Code.  The Intellisense seems to work for this code (extension BeautifulSoup):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBVQN.png)

But it doesn't work for this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqBq7.png)

I tried to restart my computer, but it didn't help.

I have also tried to use virtual enviroments and I also selected the right associated interpreter. To use python in Visual Studio Code, I installed following extensions:

- MagicPython
- Pylance
- Python
- Python Extension Pack
- Visual Studio IntelliCode

Do you have any Idea why my Intellisense is not working for packages?

Answer (score 2):

In VS Code, the "Intellisense" function of Python code is provided by the [the Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python), and the language service provided by "Pylance" provide us with docsing content.

Therefore, it is recommended that you "disable" other extensions to avoid interference between them and affect the use of the "Intellisense" function.

In addition, if it still doesn't work, please reinstall the Python extension and reload VS Code.